# How to store multiple selected values from <select> tag in a single field

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a select tag with `multiple="multiple"`. And a user can select more than one value.

```
<label for="aoi">Area of Interest:</label>
<select id="sel_aoi" name="aoi" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="hr-executive">HR Executives</option>
    <option value="sr-manager">Sr. Manager</option>
    <option value="service-advisor">Service Advisor</option>
    <option value="production">Production Engineer</option>
    <option value="mechanical">Mechanical Engineer</option>
</select>
```

How I can store these more than one selected values in single field of MySQL database?

Comment: Serialization: `$aoi = msqli_real_escape_string($db, json_encode($_POST['aoi']));`

Comment: Thanks Jared! It worked for me. There is writing mistake in the code of 'mysqli'. What is the difference in MySQL and MySQLI. It gave me a warning with mysql_connect() but worked fine with mysqli_connect().

Comment: It's not a typo. You should be using the `mysqli` library; `mysql` is old and outdated and also *deprecated*, which means it will eventually be removed. Read more about `mysqli` here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php Another option is [PHP Data Objects, or PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is an abstracted data connector which doesn't tightly couple your code to any particular library like `mysql` or `mysqli`.

Comment: Also note, when you pull it back out of the database, you deserialize with `json_decode($val)` in this case, which will give you back the original array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store it to an array and save the values to database using comma seprated.

```
<label for="aoi">Area of Interest:</label>
          <select id="sel_aoi" name="aoi[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="hr-executive">HR Executives</option>
            <option value="sr-manager">Sr. Manager</option>
            <option value="service-advisor">Service Advisor</option>
            <option value="production">Production Engineer</option>
            <option value="mechanical">Mechanical Engineer</option>
          </select>
```

process.php

```
$aoi = implode(',', $_POST['aoi']);
```

Comment: After applying our code i got a warning message:
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in ..../process.php

And no any value is stored in table.

Comment: Have you add the array to name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

When you get your values from your `$_POST` insert them in with a mysql insert multiple values like this:

```
insert into myTable 
    (someColumn, someOtherColumn) 
values 
    (someValue1, someOtherValue1), 
    (someValue2, someOtherValue2), 
    (someValue3, someOtherValue3)
```

Edit: If you want the in one row use something like PHP [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)():

```
$qry="insert into mytable (someColumn) values (".implode(',',$myArray).")
```

Not that you want to make sure that the `$myArray` variable is clean of anything that could SQJ Injection attack you database. A prepared statement would be a suggestion.

Comment: That's not what the OP is describing; it should go into one field. This is a lookup approach and the tables would need to be arranged this way to make this work (ie, normalized).

Answer (score 0):

Django models come with JSONField() which you could use to serialize the list of integer values and later deserialize it into a list.

Another appproach is: if you have limited number of options, you could also try creating separate column for each option in your database instead of saving them in single field separated by comma.

E.g

```
interest_executive: Boolean
interest_manager: Boolean
interest_service_advisor: Boolean
```

Finally, another approach is to create a separate table and have foreign key relationship between user_id and interest_name_id but this would be overkill if you have limited number of interests.