# Add data to dynamic table from modal form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page that contains a form to collect some info. As part of that is a table where I'm trying to add rows of data from a modal form. Eventually, everything would be submitted to a SQL database.

Effectively, the whole form looks like:

Field 1

Field 2

Field 3

| Field 5 | Field 6 | Field 7 | Field 8 | Delete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row |  |  | button |
| Second | row |  |  |  |

Field 9

Submit

So field 1-3 would be appended to the beginning of each row upon submission to the SQL DB and 9 to the end.

The issue I'm having is getting the data entered in fields 5-8 on the modal form to appear in the table. What would be the best way to achieve this? I'm new to this so any help would be great.

I've had a look around and I see lots of way to get data out of a table to a modal form or to enter through fields in the table and add a new row that way like this ([Add/Delete table rows dynamically using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-using-javascript)) but I'd prefer to use a modal as my form for the table will end up being quite big.

**HTML Form**

```
          <div class="card-body">
            <form action="inc/processnew.php" method="POST" id="newentry">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
                  <label>Location</label>
                  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                  <select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="location" name="location" required>
                    <option value>Select location...</option>
                    <?php echo fill_location_select_box($conn);?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
                  <label>Area</label>
                  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="area" name="area" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
                  <label>Destination</label>
                  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="destination" name="destination" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              </br>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
                  <td colspan="3"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Add New Item</a></td>
                  </br>
                  </br>
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="userList" class="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Reference</th>
                          <th>Components</th>
                          <th>Classification</th>
                          <th>Consigned</th>
                          <th>Delete?</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <label>Declaration</label>
        <span class="text-danger">*</span> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="declaration" name="declaration" value="Yes" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="md-3 col-md-6">
        <input type="hidden" value="spacer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="md-3 col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="md-3 col-md-6">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $today; ?>" id="date" name="date" required readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Modal**

```
              <div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <form name="userEntry">                 
              <div class="modal-header">
                <center>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Item</h4>
                </center>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">            
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="control-label modal-label">Reference: </label>
                      <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reference" id="reference" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </br>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="control-label modal-label">Components: </label>
                      <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="components" id="components" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </br>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="control-label modal-label">Classification: </label>
                      <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="classification" id="classification" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </br>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="control-label modal-label">Consigned: </label>
                      <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consigned" id="consigned" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </br>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-eject"></span> Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-modal-waste" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Save</a>
          </div>
                </form>
    </div>    
    </div>
      </div>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- move modal outside the form into a separate form
- add submit listener to it (also add id and disable modal dismiss)
- on modal form submit, validate data and create and append a table row, in which also add hidden inputs with values in a form of an array (`userEntry[0][reference]` etc.)
- close modal, reset modal form

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let counter = 0;

  $('#userEntry').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const rows = [];
    $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
      if (i > 0 && field.name === rows[rows.length - 1].name) {
        rows[rows.length - 1].value += ';' + field.value;
      } else {
        rows.push(field);
      }
    });

    let list = '<tr>';


    $.each(rows, function(i, field) {

      list += '<td>' + field.value + '<input type="hidden" name="userEntry[' + String(counter) + '][' + field.name + ']" value="' + field.value + '"/>' + '</td>';
    });

    list += '<td><button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();">delete</button></tr>';

    $('#userList tbody').append(list);

    $('#AddModal').modal('hide');

    counter++;

    $(this)[0].reset();


  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <form action="inc/processnew.php" method="POST" id="newentry">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <label>Location</label>
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="location" name="location" required>
          <option value>Select location...</option>
          <?php echo fill_location_select_box($conn);?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <label>Area</label>
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="area" name="area" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <label>Name</label>
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <label>Destination</label>
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="destination" name="destination" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <td colspan="3"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal">Add New Item</a></td>
        </br>
        </br>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="userList" class="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Reference</th>
                <th>Components</th>
                <th>Classification</th>
                <th>Consigned</th>
                <th>Delete?</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-md-6 error-placeholder">
        <label>Declaration</label>
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="declaration" name="declaration" value="Yes" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="md-3 col-md-6">
        <input type="hidden" value="spacer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="md-3 col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="md-3 col-md-6">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $today; ?>" id="date" name="date" required readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="userEntry">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <center>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Item</h4>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label modal-label">Reference: </label>
                <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reference" id="reference" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label modal-label">Components: </label>
                <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control select3" data-toggle="select3" id="components" name="components" multiple required>
                  <option>value1</option>
                  <option>value2</option>
                  <option>value3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label modal-label">Classification: </label>
                <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control select3" data-toggle="select3" id="classification" name="classification" multiple required>
                  <option>value1</option>
                  <option>value2</option>
                  <option>value3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label modal-label">Consigned: </label>
                <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consigned" id="consigned" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-eject"></span> Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-modal-waste"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Save</a>
                        </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, works perfectly. One of the fields on my modal is a multiselect. What would be the best way to take the values selected and to form a string with each separated by a ; for entry into the table? Previously I've just some php code but that was as it is being sent to a DB so I assume that wouldn't work here.

Comment: add `<select name="location[]" multiple...`, and then on the server you can use `implode(',', $_POST['location'])`, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922207/4321299

Comment: sorry I meant to one of the fields in the modal, say `components`. At present, it shows each option selected as a new column in the table but this should be in one column with each option separated by `;`. In the past I used `implode` when it was one big form but I don't understand how to translate that in javascript to do the same thing.

Comment: I thought it was location, since it's a multiselect.. displaying data is the same, but reading the selected options is tricky. I added `components` multiselect, try the updated code

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I take that if I were to add a second multiselect in there I would just repeat from `$.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field) {` to just above where the button is?

Comment: the `if` block in the loop, and another variable like `multiCheck`, but that would be messy, so I updated the code to first merge the same keys, and then draw the table, classification is a multiselect also

Comment: @traynor, how about to edit and update the value in row with modal?

Comment: you mean table in the "Add New Item Table"? either way, it cannot be done in a few lines, it would require a complete rewrite, and I think that's beyond the scope of this question.. One approach might be to add an "edit" button with reference to the array index, and onclick listener, and before that all data should be available, and then it would require a function which will be called upon that click, which will find the selected element in data array, display it, and then store new data.. CRUD functionality seldom comes in a few lines..